# Can I have a h264 video (without annex B) with no SPS or PPS?

Tags: video, h.264

Actually I am trying to trim a h264 video( without annex B) . I have not copied the pps and sps data to the trimmed video, but still I am able to play the trimmed video properly.

So, my question is whether its possible for a h264 video to not have any PPS or SPS data??

Answer (score 0):

Parameter sets are mandatory. Encoded picture elements are further referencing parameter sets, so they have to be available to the decoder. Trimming the bitstream, you need to prepend the resulting substream by these parameter sets.

For instance, from the spec:

> G.3.55 sequence parameter set: A syntax structure containing syntax elements that apply to zero or more layer representations with the dependency_id syntax element equal to 0 and the quality_id syntax element equal to 0 as determined by the content of a seq_parameter_set_id syntax element found in the picture parameter set **referred to by the pic_parameter_set_id syntax element found in each slice header of I, P, and B slices**.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roman.  I have just started trying my hands on video codecs. Can you please guide me where from where shall I start??